# C++ reading into a struct array inside of a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

Im trying to read a int into a struct array but im getting a error of expected expression before '[' when attempting to compile.

```
struct department {
    int id;
    char name[20];
};

int addnewdep(struct department[],int d);
int main()
{
.....
}
int addnewdep(struct department[],int d)
{
    cin >> department[d].id;
    cin >> department[d].name;
}
```

The error appears in the function definition.
Im not sure how to fix this error. any help on this would be great, thanks.

Comment: there is one `;` too much on the definition of the function

Comment: fixed that, it wasnt originally in my code so still the same error.

Comment: `struct department` is the name of a type. While it works in a declaration, you need a parameter name in the definition: `int addnewdep(struct department[],int d){...}` should be `int addnewdep(struct department department[],int d){...}` if you want the parameter to be named `department` as you are referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
  int addnewdep(department dep[], int d) {
     cin >> dep[d].id;
     cin >> dep[d].name;
  }
```

because department is name of type, not a parameter of the function. Also please note extra ; in your code.

Declaration of addnewdep() just before it's definition isn't required.

Comment: Thanks that didnt quite fix it but when i changed it to int addnewdep(struct department dep[],int d) in the definition and prototype it fixed my error. Thank you.

Comment: You still need `struct keyword`: `struct department dep[]`.